# How to clip the cell in a PdfPTable with iText?

Tags: itext, clipping, pdfptable

I am creating a one column PdfPTable given a Rectangle, at a particilar absolute position.  In this table, I need to add a collection of PdfPCells and show as much of the cell content as possible and the cells must be clipped at the table rectangle boundaries.  I took care of the width by:

```
    PdfPTable cutTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    cutTable.setTotalWidth(200f);
    cutTable.setLockedWidth(true);
```

I have a phrase object in each cell and I add a set of cells to the table.  The problem is that the cells overflows the table height boundary and it is not clipped.  I tried keeping track of the total cells' height after adding each cell, but the problem is that since I ask the table for the row height, a cell must be inserted before and my calculation is off as the last cell overflows.

How do I get the table to clip the cell contents at its boundaries?  If I can't do this, how do I determine the height of the cell(the phrase uses Arial 8 font) with the default text wrapping, before it is added to the table?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [CellHeights](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=81) example from my book "iText in Action." It uses the different options to set the height of a cell. I think you need the `setFixedHeight()` method. When using this method, all content added to the cell that doesn't fit the height will be dropped.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I have your awesome book and read Chapter 4 many times.  What I am looking for is how to determine the height of a cell with wrapped text in it before I call table.addCell(cell)? I have a table created with absolute width and height.  I have many rows of cells to insert but would like to insert up to boundaries of the table rectangle.  Setting the fixed cell height works if all rows have a fixed height.  But when you have a wrapped text inside the cells, how do you determine its height before you add the cell so the last added cell does not overflow the bottom table boundary?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do, but I know that: 1. you can't ask iText how much space a cell will take before adding it to a table because the table determines the size of the cell. 2. if you want to know how much place content takes, you can use a ColumnText object to check the content. If you use a PdfTemplate to render the column, you can reuse the PdfTemplate to create a cell. Maybe that's a solution, but... as I said: I'm not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: I had to create multi column tables with various heights.  The problem is that I had wrapped text and when I insert cells, they were not clipped to the table boundaries; therefore, you could visually see the cells overflowing/bleeding over boundary rectangle.

I worked around this problem by keeping track of the cell heights after I added the cell. If the total cell height is greater than table height, I removed the previously added cell and stopped inserting cells.  This solution works but I wished PdfPTable, given a dimension and llx, lly, it could clip the rectangle region for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand this use case, so there's very little chance this will be implemented.